# OpenID Connect (JWT) to Kerberos: protocol transition

Tags: jwt, protocols, transition, kerberos

Our authentication stack is based principally on Kerberos and now we want enlarge the offering to modern authentication like JWT based authentication (e.g. OpenID Connect). To achieve that and guarantee backward compatibility we have to provide protocol transition:

**Kerberos => JWT-based authentication (OIDC)**
This is the easy way and there are already many products that support this like

- [ADFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/active-directory-federation-services)
- [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/)
- ...

**JWT-based authentication (OIDC) => Kerberos**
This way is not trivial, there are small projects (like [this one](https://github.com/bfaviero/ok)) but seem to be old and not maintened anymore.  It seems that there is no real option for this transition.

Any inputs / suggestion on this topic?

This transition should be supported on Windows, Linux (i.e. RedHat / Centos) and containers (this should be trivial given the before requirements); Java (Spring Boot), .NET and .NET Core.

Comment: JWT isn't a protocol, whereas Kerberos is. What part of Kerberos are you trying to convert from JWT? What platform are you running on? What KDC's are you using? Protocol Transition is embodied in a spec [MS-SFU] S4U2Proxy so you'd be looking for something that implements that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-sfu/bde93b0e-f3c9-4ddf-9f44-e1453be7af5a

Comment: @Steve thanks for the reply, yes you are right, I was not so precise in my post. I changed the content to reflect your questions. The S4U2proxy topic that you proposed is unfortunately only on Kerberos (constraint delegation) and doesn't support x-authentication mechanism, or am I wrong?

Comment: You are incorrect. S4U2Proxy is exactly what you're describing. It let's you translate any auth to kerberos through  impersonation.